# Facebook integration with website - logout user from facebook if user doesn't grant permission to the app

Tags: facebook

I am working with integration of a website with facebook.

I have a specific requirement where-in the user should get logged-out from facebook if he/she doesn't grant permissions to my facebook-app (on first use).

Now, If user denies access for my facebook-app, I am redirected to the redirect_uri, but the problem is that on the page that handles the redirection, I cannot log the user out from facebook since my app won't have permission to perform logout.

Can anyone please tell me what is the workaround I could try?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a specific requirement where-in the user should get logged-out from facebook if he/she doesn't grant permissions to my facebook-app (on first use).

Is this in a *very* special environment (like a kiosk application or something) …?

Because otherwise, I’d *hate* it if random apps logged me out of FB while I’m browsing on my own computer, just because I don’t want to connect to *them*.

> Now, If user denies access for my facebook-app, I am redirected to the redirect_uri, but the problem is that on the page that handles the redirection, I cannot log the user out from facebook since my app won't have permission to perform logout.
>
> Can anyone please tell me what is the workaround I could try?

I don’t know any workaround – to perform a log out on behalf of the user, you need a valid access token – doesn’t matter, if you’re trying to do it client-side or server-side.

If that wasn’t the case, *any* website I’m visiting could log me out of Facebook, and that would be really annoying to users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Yes CBroe. This is for just the kind of 'special environment' you are telling about (kiosk application...)
The website that will be used to log-in with facebook will be opened inside an adobe AIR application.
Links to facebook timeline & other areas will be blocked. The facebook-login will only be used to publish on user's timeline...
Since other areas of facebook need to be restricted, it is important that if user chooses to 'not-authorize' the app, he/she gets logged-out from facebook.

Answer (score 0):

We have exactly the same problem. We've developed a kiosk application used to checkin and post HD photos.
If the user does not accept the permissions we need to reload the application because we can't logout the user in another way.

We've tried different ways but no one was successful